# In triangulation, what are the geometric interpretations of midpoint algorithm, homogeneous linear least squares and nonlinear least squares method?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, geometry, computer-vision, linear-algebra

In **"Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" Chapter 12. Structure Computation, page 310-313**, triangulation is used for point 3D reconstruction. There are three methods mentioned:

1. **Midpoint method** that "finds the midpoint of the common perpendicular to the two rays in space".
2. **Linear triangulation methods** that uses SVD to solve homogeneous equation `Ax = 0`. In this method **algebraic error** is minimized.
3. **Nonlinear triangulation method** that uses iterative optimization algorithms e.g. LM to solve a nonlinear least square equation `Ax = b`. The "gold standard" **reprojection error** is minimized.

My question is:

1. What are the geometric interpretations of the three methods?
2. What are the differences between the three triangulation methods above?

I did some research and found some useful information:

This [post](http://ksimek.github.io/2015/03/29/QA-recovering-pose-of-calibrated-camera/) explains that **algebraic error** assumes noise comes from 3D points, while **reprojection error** assumes noise comes from 2D image

These [slides](http://isit.u-clermont1.fr/~ab/Classes/DIKU-3DCV2/Handouts/Lecture17.pdf) introduce three methods but did not provide explicit geometric interpretations.

Comment: I think this problem is well suited here http://math.stackexchange.com/ or here http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ Because it is not a programming problem anyway!

Comment: I'd say [cs.se] rather than either of those.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll take @AakashM 's advice and pose to Computer Science.